# Use embedded tomcat instead of netty with spring-gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-cloud

I'm running this project: https://github.com/wdahlenburg/spring-gateway-demo

It uses netty by default, how can I change it to embedded tomcat instead? I've tried to modify the pom.xml and replaces `spring-boot-starter-test` with `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: It's a feature we're looking at adding. Webflux runs fine on tomcat and I've done a proof of concept

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, spring cloud gateway is build on top of reactive Spring WebFlux project and requires netty runtime, as stated in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#configuration):

> Spring Cloud Gateway requires the Netty runtime provided by Spring Boot and Spring Webflux. It does not work in a traditional Servlet Container or when built as a WAR.